# MYSQL stored procedure optimization when two statements returns two different results

Tags: python, mysql, stored-functions

My API is calling two sql statements, returning two different outputs

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k \\ 
from table_1 \\ 
left join table_2 \\
left join table_3 \\
left join table_4 \\
left join table_5 \\
")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

mycursor.execute("SELECT r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z \\
from table_6 \\
left join table_8 \\
left join table_9\\
left join table_10\\
left join table_11 \\
")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Both the select queries were talking a lot of time to execute

so, I was planning to convert this two queries into two different stored procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS statement_1;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE statement_1
BEGIN
    SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k  
    from table_1 
    left join table_2 
    left join table_3 
    left join table_4 
    left join table_5 
END //
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS statement_2;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE statement_2
BEGIN
    SELECT r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z 
from table_6 
left join table_8 
left join table_9
left join table_10
left join table_11  
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and call them

```
myresult.callproc('statement_1')
myresult.callproc('statement_2')
```

Would this method be faster, or do i need to combine these two statements into a single stored procedure using a `UNION ALL`?
Is that even possible , assuming these two statements returns totally different and unrelated outputs.

Comment: You probably just need indexes on the `join` keys.  Or perhaps your data is large and any query is going to take a long time to return the results you want.

Comment: Moving the queries to a stored procedure will not help.  Using a union will not help more than trivially.  I suggest you ask a new question for help optimizing your queries, showing output (as text, not images) of `show create table yourtablename` for all the tables and of `explain select ...rest of your query`

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**  No.  We need to look at each Select.

**Long Answer:**

Two independent `SELECTs` will not run faster via Stored Proc, `VIEW`, `UNION`, etc.

Some exceptions:

- Stored procedure with one SQL:  Probably zero difference.
- Stored procedure with both SQLs:  If the server is distant from the client, decreasing the number of SQLs shipped to the server saves network delay times.  (TransAtlantic timing is on the order of 0.1s, so this is probably not what you are seeing as "slow".)
- `VIEWs` are mostly syntactic sugar, so not likely to help in any case.
- `UNION` *may* need to generate a temp table, which could be a slight slowdown.  The temp table is avoided in the latest MySQL, `UNION ALL`, and no outside grouping or ordering.